# Windows 10 contact

Tags: contacts, windows-10

I want to allow the user to compose a list of contacts from his contact list on Windows 10 (phone or desktop).

Prior versions of Windows Phone used a ContactPicker but I am having the devil's own time finding documentation or guidance as to how to do the same thing in a Universal app.

What's it called this week? A URL would be great but I'd be more than happy with the right name so I can find the dratted thing on msdn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same. ContactPicker is available to Windows 10 apps. See the Requirements sections at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactpicker.aspx

Since it's in the Universal API contract the class is available on all devices (obviously it will only return contacts if they are available - more likely on desktop or phone than on IoT).

Comment: Thanks. I just this minute found it myself on the exact URL you have given, that's life. I actually fired up SO to answer myself, but since you've given a good answer I'm pleased to accept it. Wish I'd looked at SO three hours ago!